Machine-readable logging
I am trying to benchmark some algorithms that I have implemented. Besides other things, I want to collect statistics about objects used in a function f that's not called directly, but somewhere deeper inside the algorithm. How can I get the statistics to the outside world? Say if I call a -> b -> f, I can extend a, b, f such that they pass around the data. But that's a lot of changes. Is there a smarter way, that somewhat "collects data in the background", that I can later retrieve? I am aware of Logging.jl, but all loggers there seem to in some sense print (or discard) the data immediately, but not print it. A mockup of what I want would be
logs = Dict()
function f()
  global logs
  push!(logs, :f => "Log message from f")
end

f()

println(logs[:f])

This is very simplistic, but you get what I mean. Do you know of any package that offers this functionality?

Logging in Julia isn't really that mature yet, unfortunatly. I have been experiencing similar issues. There are various logging packages out there in the wild, but it is not easy to figure out which ones are actively maintained and would therefore be suitable to include in a project. It has actually been easier for me to modify an existing logging module which someone in our company built as a "roll your own", rather than migrate to use existing Julia packages.

Part of the reason for the difficulty is its impossible to know which of these packages work well together because they are so spread out. Rather than having a single, fully featured logging framework, we are expected to do our own research into the dozens of existing packages and figure out how to make them work together. Not a great experience, and wastes a lot of time.

The TestLogger(...) from the built-in Logging package supports this exact thing! This logger is built for testing, and stores all logs in a Vector of type LogRecord. This vector can then easily be read to find whatever logs you are looking for. A LogRecord has a bunch of fields, including a kwargs field that will be particularly helpful in reproducing your example mock-up. We can create a keyword to represent your idea of "log message from ...", and then it will be simple to parse the logs and pull out any where that keyword is equal to a particular value.

# Get the nec. packages
using Test, Logging

# Create a TestLogger
test_logger = TestLogger();

# Create example functions, and have them log some random piece of data.
f() = @info "This is the info log! My random number: $(rand())" myidentifier = :f;
g() = @warn "This is the warn log! My random number: $(rand())" myidentifier = :g;

# use the logger and call both functions
with_logger(test_logger) do
    f()
    g()
end

# Nothing will have printed out or shown as logs in the REPL. Now we read the logs.

println("Entire Logger: ", test_logger)
#=
Output:

Entire Logger: TestLogger(LogRecord[LogRecord(Info, "This is the info log! My random number: 0.6271649847098303", Main, Symbol("REPL[89]"), :Main_0994cbfd, "REPL[89]", 1, Base.Pairs(:myidentifier => :f)), LogRecord(Warn, "This is the warn log! My random number: 0.7007816573748056", Main, Symbol("REPL[90]"), :Main_2be29651, "REPL[90]", 1, Base.Pairs(:myidentifier => :g))], Info, false, (Warn, Main, Symbol("REPL[90]"), :Main_2be29651), Dict{Any, Int64}(), true)

=#


println("Just Log messages: ", [i.message for i in test_logger.logs if :f in values(i.kwargs)])
#=
Output:

Just Log messages: LogRecord[LogRecord(Info, "This is the info log! My random number: 0.6271649847098303", Main, Symbol("REPL[89]"), :Main_0994cbfd, "REPL[89]", 1, Base.Pairs(:myidentifier => :f)), LogRecord(Warn, "This is the warn log! My random number: 0.7007816573748056", Main, Symbol("REPL[90]"), :Main_2be29651, "REPL[90]", 1, Base.Pairs(:myidentifier => :g))]
=#


println("Just :f Log messages: ", [i.message for i in test_logger.logs if :f in values(i.kwargs)])
#=
Output:

Just :f Log messages: ["This is the info log! My random number: 0.6211639846090303"]
=#

println("Just :g Log messages: ", [i.message for i in test_logger.logs if :f in values(i.kwargs)])
#=
Output:

Just :g Log messages: ["This is the warn log! My random number: 0.7267826573742089"]
=#

Using this method, you can log "behind the scenes", and still retrieve any of the logging messages, while also storing pieces of data in the kwarg field.
